# What is the simplest way to get a choropleth map in pyside6 without QML?

Tags: pyside6

I am trying to get a choropleth map where every country is highlighted based on a value. Unfortunately, it seems there no simple way to do this in Pyside6. I see there is the QLocations api but that relies on QML which I am not using. Google searches either turn up no good results or suggest the QML module. What is the simplest way to get a country level choropleth map in Pyside6?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: There's no "simplest way". If want to a "Qt widgets way", then you're out of luck, since most of the modules provided by the "desktop" Qt modules are completely unrelated to what you want. Still, access and interaction with QML objects is completely possible within a QtWidgets environment, but you need to properly understand how to interact with QML (how to use it and how it works). I suggest you to start from some tutorials (like [this](//www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside-qml-qtquick-python-application/)) in order to grasp its basics, even if unrelated to what you finally want to do.

Comment: Still, the issue remains. AFAIK (but I may be wrong), the QML location API is only able to return "place" objects based on its plugins (like open street map): you do a query, and it returns an object that *also* contains country info, but there's no overall "geometry" data for specific countries. I'm afraid that you need to find a proper GIS API for that (consider looking into QGIS), possibly starting by doing proper research in the [gis.se] StackExchange site.

Comment: What *exactly* was the research you did? It seems dubious to claim that a web-search will "turn up no good results". Finding Python packages that produce these kind of maps isn't difficult. You then just need to see which of them (if any) also have PySide/PyQt support. (I won't make any recommendations myself, since that kind of discussion is off-topic on SO).

Comment: Okay, I simply went with plotly and converting it to html in a QWebEngineView(). thanks